# jQuery.get function not working in Github Pages

Tags: jquery, github

I am trying to build a project-page setup that auto populates the project details in Github using Github API. I have put up my HTML and JavaScript files in the gh-pages branch. But the `jQuery.get()` is not getting me any data. I checked with Firebug and found that the request gets sent and that response code is 200 OK, but no data is shown as received. There is no issue with the API, commandline `curl -i url` response is as expected.

My HTML is:

```
<h3>Project</h3>
<div id="project" name="sample-project"></div>
<h3>Contributors</h3>
<p id="collab"></p>
```

And my Javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var project = $('#project').attr('name');
    var baseurl = "https://api.github.com/";
    var url = baseurl + "repos/thamizha/";
    url += project;
    url += "/collaborators";
    $.get(url, function(data){
            $('#collab').text(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
});
```

Update: I tried this too. No alert even.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
$('#collab').html(JSON.stringify(data));
alert('Success');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this but you should be able to use `$.getJSON()` to do cross-domain requests:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ (check-out the `JSONP` section)

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.

**--UPDATE--**

I ran a test and if you are trying to make a cross-domain request without forcing the use of JSONP then you will receive a `200 OK` status message but no actual response. I also found this code for setting up an AJAX request in jQuery for JSONP:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: 'id=10',
  jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
  url: 'http://myotherserver.com/getdata',
  success: function () {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

This is from: http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Answer (score 1):

probably you dont have JSON api added! so JSON.stringify is not working!

just go and add this before your JS code:

```
/*
http://www.JSON.org/json2.js
2011-02-23

Public Domain.

NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

See http://www.JSON.org/js.html
*/
var JSON;if(!JSON){JSON={}}(function(){function f(n){return n<10?"0"+n:n}if(typeof Date.prototype.toJSON!=="function"){Date.prototype.toJSON=function(key){return isFinite(this.valueOf())?this.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+f(this.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+f(this.getUTCDate())+"T"+f(this.getUTCHours())+":"+f(this.getUTCMinutes())+":"+f(this.getUTCSeconds())+"Z":null};String.prototype.toJSON=Number.prototype.toJSON=Boolean.prototype.toJSON=function(key){return this.valueOf()}}var cx=/[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,escapable=/[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,gap,indent,meta={"\b":"\\b","\t":"\\t","\n":"\\n","\f":"\\f","\r":"\\r",'"':'\\"',"\\":"\\\\"},rep;function quote(string){escapable.lastIndex=0;return escapable.test(string)?'"'+string.replace(escapable,function(a){var c=meta[a];return typeof c==="string"?c:"\\u"+("0000"+a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)})+'"':'"'+string+'"'}function str(key,holder){var i,k,v,length,mind=gap,partial,value=holder[key];if(value&&typeof value==="object"&&typeof value.toJSON==="function"){value=value.toJSON(key)}if(typeof rep==="function"){value=rep.call(holder,key,value)}switch(typeof value){case"string":return quote(value);case"number":return isFinite(value)?String(value):"null";case"boolean":case"null":return String(value);case"object":if(!value){return"null"}gap+=indent;partial=[];if(Object.prototype.toString.apply(value)==="[object Array]"){length=value.length;for(i=0;i<length;i+=1){partial[i]=str(i,value)||"null"}v=partial.length===0?"[]":gap?"[\n"+gap+partial.join(",\n"+gap)+"\n"+mind+"]":"["+partial.join(",")+"]";gap=mind;return v}if(rep&&typeof rep==="object"){length=rep.length;for(i=0;i<length;i+=1){if(typeof rep[i]==="string"){k=rep[i];v=str(k,value);if(v){partial.push(quote(k)+(gap?": ":":")+v)}}}}else{for(k in value){if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value,k)){v=str(k,value);if(v){partial.push(quote(k)+(gap?": ":":")+v)}}}}v=partial.length===0?"{}":gap?"{\n"+gap+partial.join(",\n"+gap)+"\n"+mind+"}":"{"+partial.join(",")+"}";gap=mind;return v}}if(typeof JSON.stringify!=="function"){JSON.stringify=function(value,replacer,space){var i;gap="";indent="";if(typeof space==="number"){for(i=0;i<space;i+=1){indent+=" "}}else{if(typeof space==="string"){indent=space}}rep=replacer;if(replacer&&typeof replacer!=="function"&&(typeof replacer!=="object"||typeof replacer.length!=="number")){throw new Error("JSON.stringify")}return str("",{"":value})}}if(typeof JSON.parse!=="function"){JSON.parse=function(text,reviver){var j;function walk(holder,key){var k,v,value=holder[key];if(value&&typeof value==="object"){for(k in value){if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value,k)){v=walk(value,k);if(v!==undefined){value[k]=v}else{delete value[k]}}}}return reviver.call(holder,key,value)}text=String(text);cx.lastIndex=0;if(cx.test(text)){text=text.replace(cx,function(a){return"\\u"+("0000"+a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)})}if(/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g,"@").replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g,"]").replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g,""))){j=eval("("+text+")");return typeof reviver==="function"?walk({"":j},""):j}throw new SyntaxError("JSON.parse")}}}());
```

If JSON is not the issue, try fixing the datatype, like that:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
            $('#collab').text(JSON.stringify(data));
        },'json');
```

Comment: No. JSON.stringify is not an issue. I tried to access the JSON object received. Its nothing. Firebug shows correct headers and no data.