# jQuery.get not working with https on github-sites (even request to same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155974/jquery-get-function-not-working-in-github-pages) other answer, but in my case, I'm doing a simple jQuery.get request, and that too on my same domain:

```
//Now, lets pull the data for panels
var maxi = $('#mainpanel .panel[id]').length;
var count =  0;
var processed = [];
$('#mainpanel .panel[id]').each(function(index) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var turl = '/kb/resources/' + id;
    console.log('pulling data for resource',id,turl);
    $.get(turl , function(data){ 
        console.log('success');
        var dummy = document.createElement("data");
        window.dummy = dummy;
        $(dummy).append(data);
        var title = $(dummy).find('h1').text();
        var header = document.createElement("div");
        var panelBody  = document.createElement("div");
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        console.log('dbg 1');

        $(header).addClass('text-center panel-heading');
        $(header).append('<h4><a href="' + turl + '">' + title +  '</a></h4>');
        $(panelBody).addClass('panel-body panel-res-summary');
        $(panelBody).append(ul);
        console.log('dbg 2');

        $('#' + id).append($(header));
        $('#' + id).append($(panelBody));
        $(dummy).find('.container.default li').each(function(index){
            var item = $(this).find('a:first');
            var cls='';
            if (item.hasClass('imp')) cls='class="imp"'; // mark
            if ($(panelBody).height() >= 200)  return;
            $(ul).append('<li><a ' + cls + ' href="' + item.attr('href') + '">' + item.text()  + '</a></li>');
        });
        console.log('dbg 3');

        $(panelBody).append('<a class="small pull-right" href="' + turl + '"><em><u>more...</u></em></a>');
        processed.push(id);
        count += 1;
        console.log('processed');
        if (count>=maxi) {  //(count%3==0)
                msel = '#' + processed[count-1];
                msel += ' #' + processed[count-2];
                msel += ' #' + processed[count-3];
                adjustBoxes(); //Now, lets adjust the heights of all panels
                console.log('now called adjustBoxes');
            }
    });
```

The above code works fine on localhost, even in the [HTTP](http://www.prahladyeri.com) version of the site, but fails to retrieve the content in the [HTTPS](https://www.prahladyeri.com) version of the site. Since I'm making a request to the same domain, why is it not returning anything?

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, I worked-around the issue using the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054842/jquery-ajax-not-using-https). Adding a backslash at the end of the url resolves the issue, but the glitch remains. And this appears to be a glitch with the server hosting github-pages.

**EDIT 2**

As @jcaron rightly points out, the issue was definitely with my url. It was serving a `jekyll` generated static page that needed `/` at the end. And since my code was missing that, gh-pages was returning a 301 redirect and rejecting the second request. However, if gh-pages could have done a proper redirect to my ajax request, my issue would never have arisen in the first place. In short, the glitch at gh-pages end remains!

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: Chrome console says that your AJAX requests are made to the HTTP version, not the HTTPS one, when your site is requested via HTTPS – and therefor the browser blocks it as “mixed content”.

Comment: @CBroe I wonder what why the requests go to HTTP version? I've clearly written `var turl = '/kb/resources/' + id;`. Doesn't that mean the same host and protocol (HTTPS) ?

Comment: @jcaron - There is no error, the `$.get()` request callback function isn't being called at all. As you can see, I've printed the `console.log('success')` when it is called, but I don't see that message on the console anywhere.

Comment: The console should have given you an error anyway, as pointed out by @CBroe. It did so here, but for some reason I no longer get an error, and the page components load correctly now. Did you change something?

Comment: @jcaron - Yup, I changed. Accepted answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054842/jquery-ajax-not-using-https) post helped me. All I had to do was add a backslash at the end of the url. I've done the workaround now, but this looks like a glitch with the server hosting github-pages.

Comment: @PrahladYeri, your link points back here.

Comment: @jcaron Copy pasta error! I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arises because of two combined problems:

- your URL (e.g. `http://www.prahladyeri.com/kb/resources/php`) is not the actual "good" URL, it requires a redirect to add the final `/`.
- the server incorrectly redirects to the `http` rather than the `https` version.

So your code makes the request, gets a 301, tries to make a second request to the `http` URL, which is then rejected.

Two possible solutions:

- correctly include the final `/`
- fix the server to correctly redirect to the appropriate protocol

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @jcaron! I suspected something like this because I'm generating the static pages using Jekyll. And the server in question is the github-pages (hosting provided by github.com). So, fixing that is out of the question :-)). I had appended the final slash as a workaround, but good to know what was causing that.